# При попытке запуска кода выдает ошибку "Invalid Syntax", Python 3.0

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пишу такой код, а оно выдает ошибку, типа Invalid Syntax. Объясните новичку, в чем собственно проблема?

[image]

Comment: После названия функции `def create` должны идти скобочки с описанием аргументов, но у вас вместо этого идёт слово `bubble`, которое там синтаксически некорректно. Может, вам стоит убрать пробел между `create` и `bubble`?

Comment: Или там подчёркивание должно быть, а не пробел

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

В названии функции не может быть пробела.
В вопросы стоит копировать код, а не присылать скриншоты.